# Set up sqlsrv_connect() function to work correctly?

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, apache, debian

**just gonna switch to PDO, use this as reference**

I'm running Microsoft SQL Server 2022 on q4os 5.2 based on Debian 12 and I'm trying to connect to it with this code

```php
function OpenConnection() {
    $serverName = "localhost, 1433";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"db", "UID"=>"acc", "PWD"=>"87654321Abc");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if ($conn) {
        echo "Connection established.<br />";
    } else {
        echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
}
OpenConnection();
```

the page is running locally (*not docker*) with the sql server is being served from localhost (127.0.0.1) and i have the sql server drivers installed and enabled as well as the apache php extension.

and when I open this up on Apache I get an HTTP 500 error but when I don't declare the function its fine.

Can't find out how to set it up, way to many different ways I've found online.

I tried making the hostname localhost instead of q4os-desktop; *the hostname in the terminal*, different solutions I've found online, and the sample from php & microsoft without success of course.

Comment: "without success ofc" - whats OFC?

Comment: `HTTP 500 error` is a general server error status code. What does the log say the actual error is? Do you need `sqlsrv_*` I would use PDO at this point. That supports mssql, as well as other DBS so if you learn it for this you learn it for all (MySQL, PostGres, etc.).

Comment: Have you tried `$serverName = "localhost,1433";` without a space before the port number? But if it's running on the default port then you shouldn't need to specify a port number at all, so `$serverName = "localhost";` should work.

Comment: What does `localhost` resolve to? If it resolves to the `::1` IPv6 address and SQL Server's only listening on the `127.0.0.1` IPv4 address then it won't connect.

Comment: Outside of Docker containers [SQL Server for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-overview) is really only supported on some versions of RHEL, SUSE and Ubuntu, so trying to use it on Debian 12 could be "fun." Are you monitoring the errorlog file, typically at `/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog`, to confirm that the service is actually starting correctly and listening for connections?

Comment: @DaleK maybe "of course", u tell me

Comment: @user3783243 well ill try that if this doesnt work

Comment: @AlwaysLearning ill give that a go, thanks. also localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1 so yea, ive managed to connect to my server in microsoft sql server management studio and azure data studio on linux

Comment: @DaleK alright sorry about that

Comment: @AlwaysLearning also sql server does work, like i can connect to it on windows and linux and create, drop and stuff like dat

Comment: Then out of curiousity... is the PHP code running inside a Docker container (or a VS Code devcontainer, which is the same thing)? It would need to use `host.docker.internal` or the Docker host's public IP address.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning nope all native, running on apache with the php extension enabled and php with the mssql drivers enabled. had to take the hdd from my old server and put it in a different computer since the old motherboard failed so i havent had a chance to test it until now

Comment: @AlwaysLearning changing the servername to localhost didnt work

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$connection = sqlsrv_connect('YOUR_IP\MSSQL_INSTANCE_NAME',
    array(
        'UID' => 'USERNAME_MSSQL',
        'PWD' => 'PASSWORD_MSSQL',
        'Database' => 'DATABASE_NAME',
        'CharacterSet' => 'UTF-8',
    )
);
```

Comment: It's SQL Server for Linux so there's no SQL Browser service available to resolve instance names.

Comment: And please use the code formatting option in the editor rather than escaping loads of chars.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks for future answers/questions.